# lualatex: smallcaps and microtype don't work together

Tags: luatex, small-caps, microtype, opentype

Compiling the following MWE with lualatex doesn't produce small caps.
There are no font warnings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default, expansion=default}
\defaultfontfeatures{Microtype}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\textsc{foo} {\scshape bar}

\end{document}
```

Doing one of the following fixes this:

- Don't add `Microtype` to `fontfeatures`
- compile with `xelatex`

The system is a frozen TL 2011 on Archlinux.

Comment: Which version of microtype are you using? The official version, 2.4, doesn't do all that much under lualatex. Version 2.5, still in late beta, is a lot more capable.

Comment: @Mico the microtype package is not used here, it's LuaTeX own protrusion/expansion features.

Comment: One should nevertheless load `microtype` it seems. I forgot it in the example and I'm not able to edit the question though.

Comment: Unless I am very much mistaken there is absolute no point in loading the `microtype` package in your example. You could use `microtype` for letterspacing if you add `\addfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a small error in your `Microtype` syntax.

Change:

```
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default, expansion=default}% comma
```

to:

```
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default}% semicolon
```

**Edit**: If you want to use Linux Libertine consider the [`libertineotf` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertineotf).

Comment: This does the trick, thank you very much.
PS: I am using `libertineotf`, but for the sake of the MWE used `\setmainfont` here