# Smallcaps don't work if fontspec's microtype is used in luaLatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, small-caps, microtype

This could be a duplicate question of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61463/lualatex-smallcaps-and-microtype-dont-work-together) - but I'd say the problem there is still not solved.

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pdfprotrudechars=2
\pdfadjustspacing=2
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default}%
\directlua{fonts.protrusions.setups.default.factor=.5}

%\setmainfont[Microtype]{Latin Modern Roman}  

\begin{document}

\textsc{Hello World!}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Hello World!* is in smallcaps as desired, but microtype is clearly not working properly. For comparison, if one includes `\setmainfont[Microtype]{Latin Modern Roman}`:

[image]

microtype is working like a charm, but the smallcaps are not.
Loading the microtype package doesn't seem to be a good option?

## What to do to make both, microtype and smallcaps working?

Comment: Why is loading `microtype` not a choice?

Comment: @egreg I read in various questions/answers that it is a massive package which slows down lualatex quite bit (e.g. mentioned in the comments to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114742/speeding-up-compilation-using-precompiled-preamble-with-luatex)). And it is actually obsolete, as fontspec offers all features. If I have to decide between not using smallcaps or the microtype package, I may rather forgo the smallcaps. I thought that I maybe just made a mistake loading the font correctly?

Comment: I also don't get small caps with `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}` alone, so it doesn't have anything to do with microtypography. But all is fine when I explicitly specify the small caps font: `\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}`. As for `microtype` vs. `fontspec`/`luaotfload`, see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82637/7674).

Comment: @Robert Sounds promising, unfortunately I can't try it out right now. Maybe you want to write it as an answer? Is there also a command to activate fontspec's microtype and keep the font completely at default? something like `\setmainfont[microtype]`? `\setdefaultfontfeature{microtype}` does not work.

Comment: @Robert And regarding your link: Do you think `\usepackage{microtype}` will still look better than fontspec's `Microtype` even though I included these additional settings provided by the other answer? (I can barely see a difference, but will have a look at again) And would you agree that the `\usepackage{microtype}` will slow down lualatex? (I experience that.)

Comment: @Robert I finally posted your comment as an answer, as you didn't, just to get the problem solved. If you want you can write your own answer, maybe with further explanations and I will delete mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Robert in the comments, the problem has nothing to do with `Microtype`.

But by activating `Microtype` or any other font feature by

```
\setmainfont[Microtype]{Latin Modern Roman}
```

the default font settings get overwritten. Fonts which have a special subfont for **smallcaps** may not work afterwards.

By reinitializing the smallcaps subfont it will work again:

```
\setmainfont[Microtype,
             SmallCapsFont = {Latin Modern Roman Caps},
             ]{Latin Modern Roman}
```

Comment: Then, with LuaTeX is it better to use microtype or just rely on fontspec?

Comment: I guess that depends on the font itself. I can't tell for sure, please ask a new question.