# Cabin Font, Microtype, and Lualatex Produce Smallcaps---but not with Tracking=True

Tags: fonts, luatex, small-caps, microtype, lettrine

In the following MWE, I am using `Cabin` as the main font and compiling with `lualatex`.

*Remark:* I do not believe that this is a duplicate with [Smallcaps don't work if fontspec's microtype is used in luaLatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237160/smallcaps-dont-work-if-fontspecs-microtype-is-used-in-lualatex) as I am able to call in `microtype` $and$ produce smallcaps when compiling with `lualatex`---but I run into problems when I try to call in the `[tracking=true]` option in the Preamble.

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\textheight 3.75in \textwidth 6.25in
%\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{Cabin}
\setmainfont{Cabin}
\usepackage{xcolor,lettrine}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=0.25,findent=2pt]{\color{red}{S}}{mallcaps} does not happen if ``[tracking=true]'' is specified in the Preamble and I compile with \textbf{\color{red}{Lualatex}}. Is there a way to get around this, or may I safely ignore ``[tracking=true]''?
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

However, when I replace `\usepackage{microtype}` with `\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}`, the smallcaps disappear:

[image]

Question: Is there a way, and if so how, may I invoke the microtype `[tracking=true]` option and still produce smallcaps when using the `Cabin` font and compiling with `lualatex`? I need to compile with `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex` because of the usage of another font in the actual document that cannot be produced otherwise.

Thank you.

Comment: Works fine for me, i.e. as expected, with correctly tracked small caps. I am using an uptodate version of LiveTeX 2022, in case that should make a difference.

Comment: 1. If you want to use `cabin.sty` and get Cabin as the main font do `\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}` and remove `\setmainfont{Cabin}`. 2. Note `cabin` and not `Cabin` as the package name. 3. I get the expected output when tracking is enabled.

Comment: Many thanks @egreg